# Order getting successful, when both person placing order at the same time on a single quantity item (same product, quantity =1)

Tags: magento

I was trying different scenarios about the payment. Since we are a small boutique, sometimes we have only one item in stock. So I was trying a scenario where I added a product (with only one quantity in the inventory) to my cart and clicked on place order and then was filling my credit card information at the same time another person was adding the same product to his cart and clicked on place order after me. But because I was filling the information and he was paying by "cash on delivery". What happened is that we both got the confirmation email and the payment was successful. So how this is possible? When I checked the inventory it was (-1) and not (0). I tried again but this time , I filled the credit card information and clicked "pay now" and then the other person clicked "place order". In this case the cash on delivery one didn't get the order. which is what it should have happened in the first time.

Comment: have you tried changing System > Inventory > Product Stock Option > Backorders to "No Backorders"?

Comment: I didn't change anything, System > Configuration->Inventory > Product Stock Option > Backorders  value is "No Backorders" only